# Object/model is invisible in render and stays that way despite trying a lot of solutions out (v. 2.8)

Tags: rendering, objects, camera, visibility

As the title mentioned all of my objects are invisible whenever I render or look at a rendered view of my objects through the camera perspective. I made sure that:

- no object is hidden and unhid everything again to be sure
- Camera is positioned in the right way
- that the ray visibility in renders for the camera tickbox is ticked
- the shader settings and nodes for all materials add up to a material output
- that all the other general settings for commonly suggested solutions, etc. are correct

Also:

- I created the objects/models here within the v2.79 of blender, where rendering images and animations in cycles went perfectly without problems
- I got it updated to the 2.8 version relatively recently and am still a bit unfamiliar with the navigation there and may have overlooked a few settings or options there

I would apreciate it if someone could help me out on this one here.

Comment: Have you checked the restriction toggle for disabling the object (or collection) in the render (camera icon)?

Comment: That setting is hidden in the top of the Outliner to the right, under filter. May be the case. A Picture or blend file could help more though in regards of finding the problem.